# Eclipse linker order between shared and static libraries

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, linker, eclipse-cdt

I want to compile an executable in eclipse CDT (RHEL 6.3). I want to link couple of libraries - some of them are static, and some are shared. The order is important because of the linker.

I write the shared libraries under the `settings -> linker -> libraries`.
In order to avoid a linker property of preferring `.so` over `.a` library, I want to write the full path of my static libraries, so I can't write it in the `settings -> linker -> libraries` - because it will get the `-l` option - which isn't corrent. I must write it in the `settings -> linker -> miscellaneous`.

When writing my static libraries I'm afraid of the linker to get the `.so` library because some libraries might be in the `/usr/lib` path, so the linker will prefer the `.so` lib from there (even though I would tell him where to look for my static library with `-L`, there will be two libraries, with the same name in different paths, one `.so` and the other `.a`, so the linker will choose the `.so`.

I don't want to delete libraries from `/usr/lib`.

**Now for the problem**:
for optimizations, the libraries need to be in order of dependency (from the linker), eclipse tries to link first the `miscellaneous`, and then the `libraries` (or the opposite) - but I the order to be in "higher resolution", there are some shared libraries that depend on static libraries, and the opposite.

Is there a solution for this problem?
Can I write the static libraries in another place so it will be in order with the shared libraries?